# How to create layout withminimum and maximum height?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I have two layout layout1 and layout2 in linear layout with vertically gravity.
standard layout1 height for me is for example 300dp (big height for small displays).

In small displays this takes almost all of the view height. But I want to take layout1 maximum height 50% of the view.

If I set height 50% of all height view in big displays I have some loss space.
[image]
If I set height 300dp in small displays I just have layout1.
[image]
So I have to limit for layout1 height, 50% for weight in small displays and 300dp for dpi in large displays.
how can I set this limits to my layout1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At runtime, you can determine how much space your LinearLayout1 is taking up, and adjust its height only if it takes more than half of the screen. To do this, use following code.

Suppose you have given your LinearLayout1 the id as R.id.LL1, then using this code, you can ask android to adjust height of LL1 to 50%

```
int screenHeight, screenWidth;

//Code to determine screen's height and width.

Display display = getWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
if (android.os.Build.Version.SDK_INT>=13) {
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenHeight = size.x;
    screenWidth = size.y;
}
else {
    screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    screenHeight = display.getHeight();
}


LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL1);

int layoutHeight = ll.getLayoutParams().height; // gets layout's height

if ((layoutHeight * 2) > screenHeight) { 

    // true when LL1 takes more than half of screen, good time to set it back to 50% height

    ll.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight/2;
    ll.requestLayout(); //Forces layout to be adjusted.
}

else {
//All good, no work required, so skip this else block
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your attention. whats getWindowManager? is it a lib ,class am i should to add something to my project? when i use your code eclipse can't recognize that.

Comment: @max reffer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindowManager()). This is a method provided by Activity class to work with windows (of android :P)

Answer (score 1):

do you know about weigth?

If you want 2 Layouts (L1 50%) (L2 50%) height use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         >
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and if you want diferents % in screen size(large,small), create another xml with the same name but different weight for each one.

Example: `res/layout-large/activity_main.xml` or `res/layout-small/activity_main.xml`  change only the weight.

More information: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by comparing ScrollView's height with Screen Width(Can Compare with Height - Based on your requirement) :

```
if (myScrollView.getHeight > ((int)(screenWidth * 0.8))) {

    myScrollView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(screenWidth * 0.85);

}
```

Actually i'm adding views dynamically. Once ScrollView's height reached to certain limit fixed the height.